# Cocoa application with an optional command line mode

Tags: cocoa, scripting, cmd

I'm about to start a new Cocoa project from scratch and one of the requirements I have already been given is being able to choose either a Cocoa GUI or a command line mode from the same executable.  Scriptability may be a possible addition in the future but that is not a concern right now.

What is the best strategy for going about this in Cocoa, especially if I want to maintain certain Cocoa features like Obj-C garbage collection?

Comment: GC has nothing to do with it, since GC is not dependent on AppKit or the window server.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode will generate a main.m for you with a main function that has the command line arguments.   You should parse them and if you need to stay in command-line mode, never do the application startup.  If you are being a GUI, just start normally.

Comment: Is there a way to get this functionality for a Swift-only project that has no main.m?

Comment: I haven't checked it, but look at `CommandLine.arguments` in the app delegate's didFinishLaunching or willFinishLaunching -- you should be able to exit after handling the arguments if present.