# Is it possible to run a Swift-only Cocoa application in command-line mode

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, command-line

I am writing a document-driven Cocoa app for which I want to create a special "command-line mode" which will not launch any windows and requires no user interaction.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390914/cocoa-application-with-an-optional-command-line-mode) from 2010 asks the same question, but for older Cocoa projects that included a main.m file.  Is it possible to do this for a modern Cocoa app that uses only Swift and thus does not have a main.m?

Comment: A Swift app can certainly have a _main_ file.

Comment: @matt a new project created in Xcode 10.1 that uses Swift does not come with a main.m file.  Are you suggesting that adding a main.m file to such a project is a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In Xcode select `File > New > Target > Command Line Tool` and select Swift as the language. This will add main.swift in a separate target that you can bundle with your app.